# How to remove previous eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var keyPress = function(){
    x = document.querySelector(".textt");
    x.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
       var keyp = document.querySelector(".textt").value;
       console.log(event);
       document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
           create(event);
           x.value = "";
        })
    })
}
    
var create = function(event){
    var out = document.querySelector(".output");
    var displa = document.createElement('li');
    displa.textContent =  "The key Code for " + event.key + " is: " + event.keyCode;
    out.appendChild(displa);
}
    
function clearAll(){
    location.reload();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title> ASCI </title>
</head>
<body>
   <p> Enter any Character </p>
   <form>
       <input class="textt" type="text" id = "inp" onkeypress="keyPress()">
    </form>
    <button id="tt" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        
    <ul class="output">
    </ul> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output1: First time when I press a key I'm able to get keycode
The key Code for a is: 65
 **

**Output2: Second time I press key I'm able to get keycodes but it also gives me output for previous key as well as the 2 times the for the new key pressed
The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for b is: 66
The key Code for b is: 66
 **
Can someone help me to resolve this? I only want the output for the new key pressed not previous ones's.

Comment: Why do you have an `onkeypress` event that calls the `onkeyup` event.  `onkeyup` should suffice to kick off your event.

Comment: Should I remove onkeypress from HTML? But if i do so how would I trigger my event? **I'm beginner need liitle more help**

Comment: I removed it from HTML and called function keyPress() in my js. After pressing a and b key I got the following output:The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for b is: 66

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x.onkeyup = null;
```

Before the x.addEventListener line. It'll clear the previous event listener before assigning the new one.

Comment: Still doesn't works. Output: The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for a is: 65
The key Code for b is: 66

Answer (score 0):

the previous answer is correct, only if the event handlers were assigned using `element.event = function`. For the `addEventListener` method, `removeEventListener` is required to deal with these.

Usage:

```
element.removeEventListener("the event", the function you want to remove);
```

But in your case, you used an anonymous function for the handler. It should be like this.

```
function myFunc(){
  console.log("hello world");
}
element.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
element.removeEventListener("click", myFunc);

// This does not work
myFunc = function(){...};
// This also does not work
element.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("hello world");});
element.removeEventListener("click", function(){console.log("hello world");});
```